# I am not able to get the values from the database in the order I want

Tags: android, database, sqlite, union, bar-chart

I am trying to get the values from database for a bar chart in android.

```
id   amount  status   month
1    3567       +      4
2    5673       -      3
3    2356       +      2
4     789       -      8
5    1789       +      8
```

Please consider this table. (I'm sorry I could not add an image). Since, I need to get the values for a bar chart, I am wanting to have month on the x-axis and amount on the y-axis. The bar chart should be income vs expense chart.

I have applied the following query:

```
Cursor c=db1.rawQuery("select distinct month, (select sum(amount) from expenses where status like '+' group by month) as income, (select sum(amount) from expenses where status like '-' group by month)as expense from expenses", null);
```

and I am getting the following result:

```
month   income   expense
4       2356       5673
3       2356       5673
2       2356       5673
8       2356       5673
```

instead of

```
month    income    expense
4        3567       null
3        null       5673
2        2356       null
8        1789       789
```

I want that if there are more rows where (let's say, month=4 and status="+", amount=20), then 3587 should be the result instead of 3567.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct month, 
    (select sum(amount) from expenses where month = t.month and status like '+' group by month) as income, 
    (select sum(amount) from expenses where month = t.month and status like '-' group by month) as expense 
from expenses t
```

Comment: it's working perfectly fine. Thanks a ton! could you also please tell me how can I make the month to appear in sorted order in my graph?

Comment: `... from expenses t order by month`

Comment: I forgot to include, month in database is in int. and the month that I am using for bar chart is String array, i.e. month2[] which I have converted from month only. How do I sort it now?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand that. Can you show your creating table query?

Comment: basically, I am asking how to sort an array of strings month-wise, like..Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr.....

Comment: Strings you can sort only by alphabet. With months you can use additional table with fields `number` and `name`. In `expenses` table use `number` value and sort by it. When you want to show info to user use `name` value. For example:

`select distinct (select name from Months where number=t.month), 
    
    (select sum(amount) from expenses where month = t.month and status like '+' group by month) as income, 
    
    (select sum(amount) from expenses where month = t.month and status like '-' group by month) as expense 

from expenses t order by month`

Comment: you got me wrong. I wasn't asking that w.r.t. database.

Comment: Do you want to sort `String[]` container or sort `int` values in database and get month name by them?

Answer (score -2):

where u do a sub-query, u need join the data because the sub-query will search in all the table(s).
srry i dont have seen that was only 1 table try this too.

```
select 
   distinct month,
   (select sum(ammount) from foo as f2 where f1.month=f2.month and status='+' ) as income,
   (select sum(ammount) from foo as f3 where f1.month=f3.month and status='-') as expense
from foo f1
```

Comment: there is only one table.